What's the difference between these two functions for 394. Decode String?
I am trying to solve 394. Decode String on Leetcode, this was my solution (I know it's inefficient):
class Solution:
    def decodeString(self, s: str) -> str:
        stack = []

        for ch in s:
            if ch != ']':
                stack.append(ch)
            else:
                new_s = ''
                while stack[-1] != '[':
                    new_s += stack.pop()
                new_s = new_s[::-1]
                stack.pop()

                number = ''
                while stack and stack[-1].isdigit():
                    print(stack[-1])
                    number += stack.pop()
                number = int(number[::-1])

                
                print(new_s)
                stack.append(number * new_s)
        
        return "".join(stack) 

and this is the working solution:
class Solution:
    def decodeString(self, s: str) -> str:
        stack = []

        for ch in s:
            if ch != ']':
                stack.append(ch)
            else:
                # Collect the characters forming the encoded string
                decoded_string = []
                while stack[-1] != '[':
                    decoded_string.append(stack.pop())
                stack.pop()  # Remove the '['
                
                # Now reverse the decoded string to get the correct order
                decoded_string = ''.join(decoded_string[::-1])
                
                # Get the number (how many times to repeat)
                number = []
                while stack and stack[-1].isdigit():
                    number.append(stack.pop())
                number = int(''.join(number[::-1]))

                # Append the repeated decoded string back to the stack
                stack.append(number * decoded_string)
        
        return "".join(stack)

Why is the first function not working? I really think that there is no difference except that I am reversing a string, and the correct code reverses the list.
Input: 3[z]2[2[y]pq4[2[jk]e1[f]]]ef
Output:
zzzyypqfejkjkfejkjkfejkjkfejkjkyypqfejkjkfejkjkfejkjkfejkjkef

Expected:
zzzyypqjkjkefjkjkefjkjkefjkjkefyypqjkjkefjkjkefjkjkefjkjkefef

I just don't see why one algo works and the other doesn't...

Which test does it fail on?  Clearly, it works on the three samples.

Hi Tim, it fails on this:
"3[z]2[2[y]pq4[2[jk]e1[f]]]ef"
output : "zzzyypqfejkjkfejkjkfejkjkfejkjkyypqfejkjkfejkjkfejkjkfejkjkef"
expected: "zzzyypqjkjkefjkjkefjkjkefjkjkefyypqjkjkefjkjkefjkjkefjkjkefef"

so we can see that there is some weird behavior happening with "ef" being in the wrong place, but I don't get why :(

What does "not working" mean? What's the expected behavior? Have you tried stepping line by line through both codes at the same time with your debugger to compare the behavior?

@jabaa everything is in the comments above. thank you

Please add all details to the question. Comments are often deleted after some time and not stored in the history. Many users don't read all comments. I can't find a description of the codes in the comments. I can't find your debugging results in the comments. Thank you.

Please edit the question to explain what the code is supposed to do. We don't know LeetCode problems by name.

A simpler input is 2[2[ab]]. The first approach returns babababa and the second approach returns abababab. This short input should be easier to debug.

Check out How to debug small programs by Eric Lippert. Where you have the working code to compare with, the rubber duck step should be a lot shorter :) Although, with this program, some of the other steps might not be super useful or practical, like breaking up your code and writing specs.

Thank you @Barmar for suggestions. sorry this is my first post, so I am learning :)

The difference here is subtle.  If you had printed the stack at the end of each loop, you'd see it.  Here's a stack trace of your code:
['zzz', '2', '[', 'yy', 'p', 'q', '4', '[', 'jkjk']
['zzz', '2', '[', 'yy', 'p', 'q', '4', '[', 'jkjk', 'e']
['zzz', '2', '[', 'yy', 'p', 'q', '4', '[', 'jkjk', 'e', '1']
['zzz', '2', '[', 'yy', 'p', 'q', '4', '[', 'jkjk', 'e', '1', '[']
['zzz', '2', '[', 'yy', 'p', 'q', '4', '[', 'jkjk', 'e', '1', '[', 'f']
['zzz', '2', '[', 'yy', 'p', 'q', '4', '[', 'jkjk', 'e', 'f']
['zzz', '2', '[', 'yy', 'p', 'q', 'kjkjefkjkjefkjkjefkjkjef']
['zzz', 'yypqfejkjkfejkjkfejkjkfejkjkyypqfejkjkfejkjkfejkjkfejkjk']


Vs their code:
['zzz', '2', '[', 'yy', 'p', 'q', '4', '[', 'jkjk']
['zzz', '2', '[', 'yy', 'p', 'q', '4', '[', 'jkjk', 'e']
['zzz', '2', '[', 'yy', 'p', 'q', '4', '[', 'jkjk', 'e', '1']
['zzz', '2', '[', 'yy', 'p', 'q', '4', '[', 'jkjk', 'e', '1', '[']
['zzz', '2', '[', 'yy', 'p', 'q', '4', '[', 'jkjk', 'e', '1', '[', 'f']
['zzz', '2', '[', 'yy', 'p', 'q', '4', '[', 'jkjk', 'e', 'f']
['zzz', '2', '[', 'yy', 'p', 'q', 'jkjkefjkjkefjkjkefjkjkef']
['zzz', 'yypqjkjkefjkjkefjkjkefjkjkefyypqjkjkefjkjkefjkjkefjkjkef']

Do you see it?  When the stack contains a multi-character string, your code inverts the whole string, so "jkjkef" becomes "fekjkj".  THEIR code inverts the list and combines the result, producing "fejkjk".  The strings within the list maintain their ordering, as they should.

Thank you so much! I got it now. Very beautiful explanation
